# How to load function with dlsym() without reinterpret_cast?

Tags: c++, clang-tidy

I'm trying to use clang-tidy to enforce the C++ Core Guidelines. While it does have a lot of valid points, there is one thing I cannot really work around: dlsym returns a `void*` which I need to turn into a proper function pointer somehow. To do that I use `reinterpret_cast`. Since the guidelines forbid it, I have warnings about it.
Of course I can put `//NOLINT` comments everywhere, but I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use `reinterpret_cast` so the warnings go away.

Are there any workarounds for this problem?

Comment: No way. It's a well known problem.

Comment: Just casting from `void*` to a function pointer type is sketchy from a language perspective. Object pointers and function pointers are not compatible types and aren't guaranteed to even have the same size. Though any compiler for platforms that provides `dlsym` have to contend with that in some way. The fact that a function that returns function pointers does so through `void*` is just overall problematic.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux casting from object pointers to function pointers and vice versa is *conditionally supported*. If a platform offers `dlopen`, it probably suports such casting.

Comment: Create a wrapper for `dlsym`, so you'll only need to use `//NOLINT` once in the wrapper.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux the standard requires that *if* an implementation supports a conditionally-supported feature *then* it must obey certain rules about it. Yes  "shall yield the original pointer value" is such a rule.

Comment: You *could* use C-style cast... but I expect that also violates guidelines and is a worse solution than simply not enforcing the guidelines. They are only guidelines rather than language rules for a reason.

Comment: Interestingly, it seems that GCC does not document the behavior of `reinterpret_cast` in this case. At least there seems to be nothing [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionally-supported-behavior.html#Conditionally-supported-behavior)? Does anyone know of any such documentation? Because, technically, a lack of such documentation would make GCC a non-conforming implementation!?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Unfortunately, that won't help here as `static_cast` cannot perfom the cast required…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel: you can consider GCC's source code as documentation :) At least, I don't see that the standard specifies what a documentation is.

Comment: @geza good point! I was wondering where to look, especially since this is something that will potentially vary depending on target architecture…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel Bloody function pointers.

Comment: @KonradRudolph indeed

Comment: With two type-casts: `(function *)(intptr_t)dlsym(...)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no other way in the language to cast a function pointer type to an object pointer type except for `reinterpret_cast`. Doing so is implementation-defined behavior [[expr.reinterpret.cast]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#8):

> Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported. The meaning of such a conversion is implementation-defined, except that if an implementation supports conversions in both directions, converting a prvalue of one type to the other type and back, possibly with different cv-qualification, shall yield the original pointer value.

That means that a conforming C++ compiler *must* document if it does *not* support this feature. And, if it does support it, it *must* document how exactly it behaves. You can rely on it working (or not being available) in the documented way on that compiler.

Concerning the Core Guidelines linting: If you would have to put `//NOLINT` "everywhere", then that would seem to imply that you're calling naked `dlsym()` in many places. Consider wrapping it, for example

```
template <typename T>
inline T* lookupSymbol(void* module, const char* name)
{
    auto symbol = reinterpret_cast<T*>(dlsym(module, name));  // NOLINT

    if (!symbol)
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to find symbol '"s + name + '\'');

    return symbol;
}
```

Comment: @KonradRudolph It seems that the paragraph quoted above was introduced in C++11, so it would seem to me that at least these kinds of contortions should not be required anymore…

Comment: I added `using pT = T*;` in the function and then I can use function style cast like `pT(dlsym(module, name))` and clang-tidy doesn't bite for that.

Comment: @Calmarius Well, that's just a very roundabout way of doing the same thing. Your function-style cast in this case is defined to be equivalent to a C-style cast [\[expr.type.conv/2\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.type.conv#2), which is defined to be equivalent to a `reinterpret_cast` in this case [\[expr.cast/4\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.cast#4)…