# What is the C++ way of interpreting the void* returned by dlsym as a pointer-to-function?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, void-pointers, dynamic-library, dlsym

Assume a dynamic library exports a function, e.g. of type `void()`, named `foo`. A client code could then make use of it like in the following snippet (assuming `foo` is exposed via `extern "C" void foo();` for simplicity)

```cpp
#include "Foo.hpp" // defines the type of foo

// dlopen a library and check it was found

// look for a symbol foo in a library lib
void * fooPtr = dlsym(lib, "foo");

// if reading the symbol succeeded
if (!dlerror()) {
  // use it
  using Foo = decltype(foo);
  ((Foo*)fooPtr)();
}
```

I've understood that [`static_cast` is not usable here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74002657/why-cant-i-static-cast-a-void-to-a-pointer-to-function), but is the above C-style cast the way to go?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55362913/how-to-load-function-with-dlsym-without-reinterpret-cast

Comment: @ecatmur, yeah, probably that's an answer to my question. I'll let others mark this as dup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load function with dlsym() without reinterpret\_cast?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55362913/how-to-load-function-with-dlsym-without-reinterpret-cast)

Comment: There are different methods, but the result is the same (i.e. the actual 32/64 bits of the pointer aren't changed), so no need to put too much effort into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C-style cast is [required in archaic versions of C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1096349/567292). [Since C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36964600/567292), `reinterpret_cast` from object pointer to function pointer type is [conditionally-supported](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#8) and should be used if possible:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
  reinterpret_cast<Foo*>(fooPtr)();
#else
  ((Foo*)fooPtr)();
#endif
```

If the implementation supports `dlsym` (which is part of POSIX), it almost certainly supports `reinterpret_cast` from object pointer to function pointer type.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is clearer, but it has the same effect as the C-style cast. So if the latter needs to be supported it seems pointless to conditionally use `reinterpret_cast`. Actually, did you maybe intent to reinterpret the pointer itself in the else-branch? That is the aliasing-violating approach I am have seen when the cast between object and function pointer is not supported at all.

Comment: By using the `reinterpret_cast` form, you can ensure that when your codebase drops support for C++03 the clearer form is retained. I'd have thought that even a C++03 compiler should support the C-style cast (to support C-compiled-as-C++), but I've more or less forgotten how such archaic compilers tended to work.